# Android Activity end of life

Tags: android, android-activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, address);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm starting with this code a new Activity and try to close the recent one, if I execute the seconds Activity starts and the Apps quits without a error-warning.
Under Android it works fine 2.3, under 2.2 it quits.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, address);        
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This way your current activity will be stoped and you are intented to new activity.

Comment: nope, this doesn't change anything, the second activity shows up for under 1 sec and app closes. If it may help, its my Main (starting) Activity

Answer (score 2):

It quits without errors because you are calling `finish()` on the activity before you call `startActivity()`. When you call `startActivity()` it pushes the intent into a queue of events for the near future. `finish()` starts the activity's cleanup. Maybe there is different priority of these events between 2.2 and 2.3.

Comment: as mentioned above, it doesn't matter, its not the priority

Comment: why not finish the current activity in it's `onStop()` method?